# snakemake adjust timelimit based on restart attempt

Tags: python, bioinformatics, slurm, snakemake

I have a workflow that requires an embarrassingly parallel step with different resource requirements (memory and time) for a slurm cluster. I decorated the workflow as per documentation:

```
rule freebayes:
    ...
    resources:
        mem = lambda wildcards, attempt: attempt * 6144,
        time = lambda wildcards, attempt: attempt * 12 * 60
    ...
```

This is successfully submitted and the memory requirement is properly requested, but the `time` requirement is set to the default value in the config file. In the log it seems ok:

```
resources: mem=6144, time=720
```

I also tried requesting time as a string:

```
time = lambda wildcards, attempt: str(attempt * 12) + ":00:00"
```

which also submitted ok but still set to default time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just noticed what I was doing wrong. My cluster.json was overriding the request because of the following line:

```
"__default__":
{
    "time": "24:00",
},
```

I removed it and now it works fine.